# activemq in servicemix

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-servicemix

I have a bundle with my implementation of managing messaging with activemq queue. I want to deploy this bundle on servicemix however I dont know the broker URL which I should use. 
when I deployed this on standalone activemq server I used following URL for brokerURL: tcp://localhost:61616.

However this does not seem to work (or I think I might me missing some config to tell servicemix to use this url as activemq broker URL).

I can see activemq as installed when i run features:list command on servicemix.

Can anyone please help me in finding how/what broker URL I should use to correctly deploy my application on servicemix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included some repo location for property org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories in <>/etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn file, which made this connection exception disappeared.

NOTE: I am not sure how come adding these repo, resolved the connection issue, however I am hoping that adding repo location in property file (as above) might have helped servicemix accessing some API to make connection.